# White screen (with and without black lines) after a boot

Tags: kernel, updates, 16.10, white-screen

I've just installed the most recent updates to my system 16.10, some of which were Linux kernel updates (4.8.0-42).

After the suggested reboot, the system has become unusable: after the BIOS screen I see a white screen, which after some time (I suppose, which is required to put the monitor to sleep) shows vertical black lines:
[image: ubuntu-white-screen-black-lines]

I was able to load from the Grub menu a previous version of the linux-kernel, 4.8.0-41, but what am I supposed to do now?

Remove the updates, load from now on with the Grub advanced options?

Please, could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this turned out to be the next:

Wait for the next update of the Linux kernel and until that use the previous working Linux kernel, selecting it from the Grub load menu, which one can access by pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during the computer's boot.

With the next update of the kernel the issue has gone in my case.